# Image not showing for multiple image upload with active storage

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have followed a tutorial on how to upload multiple images using active record. I have installed active record, added my associations to my model and when I create a Service (my model) everything seems to be working when I upload 3 images i.e no Active Record errors however I cannot see my images on the FE, all I see is a broken images.

When I go into Rails c and type Service.images.last I can see that images is nil. Does anyone know why this is?

Is there anything else you need to know or see from me?

Thank you

My code to show the image:

```
<%=@service.images.each do  |img| %>
  <%= cl_image_tag @service.images, crop: :fill, class: 'card-image', class: 'card-image-show'%>
 <%end %>
```

Rails c

```
  Service Load (59.6ms)  SELECT  "services".* FROM "services" ORDER BY "services"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<ActiveStorage::Attached::Many:0x00007fffc3ff08a0 @name="images", @record=#<Service id: 14, name: "Test Carpet cleaning", description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing a...", picture_url: nil, video: nil, category: "carpet cleaning", created_at: "2019-08-19 12:32:35", updated_at: "2019-08-19 12:32:35", photo: nil, images: nil>, @dependent=:purge_later>
```

Rails c when i do Service.last.images

```
irb(main):013:0> Service.last.images
  Service Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "services".* FROM "services" ORDER BY "services"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<ActiveStorage::Attached::Many:0x00007f92fd1f8780 @name="images", @record=#<Service id: 15, name: "test multiple images", description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing a...", picture_url: nil, video: nil, category: "carpet cleaning", created_at: "2019-08-19 18:56:12", updated_at: "2019-08-19 18:56:13", photo: nil, images: nil>, @dependent=:purge_later>
```

Service model

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end
```

I would like my 3 images to display on the FE

Comment: in the console when you do `Service.last.images.count ` do you get 3?

Comment: Hello @MZaragoza yes I do! All i can see on my front end is broken images and the active record string from the console.

Comment: on the ERB file if what do you get when you do  `<%=@service.images.each do  |img| %>
  img
  <br>
<%end %>

Comment: I get this  on the front end ``img 
img 
img 
[#<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 16, name: "images", record_type: "Service", record_id: 15, blob_id: 16, created_at: "2019-08-19 18:56:12">, #<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 17, name: "images", record_type: "Service", record_id: 15, blob_id: 17, created_at: "2019-08-19 18:56:13">, #<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 18, name: "images", record_type: "Service", record_id: 15, blob_id: 18, created_at: "2019-08-19 18:56:13">]``

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I finally used to get the imageS to show on my SHOW PAGE.

```
<% if @service.images.attached? %>
<p>
  <strong>Images:</strong>
  <br>
  <% @service.images.each do |image| %>
    <%= image_tag(image) %>
  <% end %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

I was using `cl_image_tag` to display my image which was causing the image to display broken. I should have used the above.

Source:https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/rails-5-2-active-storage-and-beyond